# Python and R good tutorials?

Tags: machine-learning, r, python

I would like to learn both Python and R for usage in data science projects.

I am currently unemployed, fresh out of university, scouting around for jobs and thought it would be good if I get some Kaggle projects under my profile.

However, I have very little knowledge in either language. Have used Matlab and C/C++ in the past. But I haven't produced production quality code or developed an application or software in either language. It has been dirty coding for academic usage all along.

I have used a little bit of Python, in a university project, but I dont know the fundamentals like what is a package , etc etc. ie havent read the intricacies of the language using a standard Python Textbook etc..

Have done some amount of coding in C/C++ way back (3-4 years back then switched over to Matlab/Octave).

I would like to get started in Python Numpy Scipy scikit-learn and pandas etc. but just reading up Wikipedia articles or Python textbooks is going to be infeasible for me.

And same goes with R, except that I have zero knowledge of R.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This is probably off topic if you're just asking for tutorials and resources. Please elaborate with the specific issues you are facing with these tools.

Comment: Here are some guidelines about posts here. http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2):

There is an online data science "game" that takes you from learning how to use Python for loading a csv and using scikit to machine learning algorithms such as support vector machines. Here is a [blog post](http://mentally-physically-spiritually-strong.com/2014/10/18/explore-data-science-game/) with a demo video and the actual site is [Explore Data Science](https://exploredatascience.com). Personally, I think its genius.

Comment: Look pretty cool, but also a bit expensive. Anyway I like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the video tutorial/IPython notebook format really helped me get into the python ecosystem.

There were two tutorials at SciPy 2013 that cover sklearn ([part 1 of 1st tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4bRUvvlaBw), [github repo for notebooks](https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_scipy2013)).

Similar tutorials, from PyCon2012 and PyData2012, are out there for pandas but I don't have the rep to link searching for `pandas tutorial` on youtube should allow you to find them.

Since you mention Kaggle, I guess you will have seen their getting started with python tutorial for the titanic passenger dataset (I don't have the rep here to provide a link but searching for `Getting Started with Python: Kaggle's Titanic Competition` should get you there).

Answer (score 1):

There are really so many good resources now.  If you want to stay away from textbooks, both O'Reilly Media and Packt Publishing offer much lighter but effective reading on a lot of great topics.  These books are much more applied in practice.

As far as learning the languages go, Coursera, Udacity, Code Acadmey, and Code School have great tutorials.  I would recommend taking a look at the following:

**[Coursera AI and Stats Courses](https://www.coursera.org/courses?orderby=upcoming&lngs=en&cats=stats,cs-ai)**

**[Udacity Data Science courses](https://www.udacity.com/courses#!/data-science)**

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) by Hadley Wickham. I think it is at the same time incredibly rich in content and easy to read. You say you have zero knowledge in R, but I believe since you already have programming skills in other languages this book can complement very fruitfully any classical "R beginner manual" (for the latter see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html#english)).

Answer (score 0):

*The Art of R Programming* by Normal Matloff is a great way to find your way towards being an R user.  I've recommended this book to several people navigating the tutorial / book universe and to my knowledge they've all stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

The [R Programming Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming) is a nice collaborative handbook for R.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend those materials:

- Python

  - [Python for Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449319793) - book which nicely covers Pandas workflow with IPython.
  - [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491962291) - slightly more advanced book about using Scikit-Learn and Tensor flow in data science projects
- R

  - [Coursera Data Science Specialisation](https://www.coursera.org/specialization/jhudatascience/1?utm_medium=listingPage) - free nine one month time consuming courses which introduces R step by step from beginning to machine learning.
  - [Data Camp courses](https://www.datacamp.com/courses) - at least 4 free courses covering topics from data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer quick hands-on/interactive tutorials, below are my suggestions -

Python - [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/), Google Python Class

R - CodeSchool's ['Try R'](http://tryr.codeschool.com/) and DataCamp (suggested above)

Answer (score 0):

Also, **[Green Tea Press](http://www.greenteapress.com/index.html)** offers free books on related topics such as an intro to Python and using python with Probability and Stats.